# SpringBoot application throwing "Broken Pipe" time to time

Tags: spring-boot, docker, broken-pipe

I have a springboot application that consume a xml and its running inside a docker container. When I do a load testing for that at some point its throwing "Broken pipe" error. I'm increasing traffic by 20% continuously with 5min gap (100% traffic is around 300 requests per 10 seconds). Used the goreplay tool for the traffic sending. From the begining also time to time this error throw and its less count (around 4 to 8 per 10 seconds but not continuously). But around 280% traffic level this error count is very high and continuously occuring.

Can please anyone let me know what can be the reasons for this and how to resolve this? Or what area I need to check to fix this.
With the monitoring graphs I couldn't see any server matrics limit exceed or any other errors in the logs. Getting the error as below.

Thank you.

```
[org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe]] with root cause
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:118) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.4
4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:151) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1367) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9
.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:766) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.writeBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:586) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9
.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.write(SocketWrapperBase.java:530) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:546) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9
.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.doWrite(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:112) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar
!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:606) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flushByteBuffer(OutputBuffer.java:783) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44
]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.append(OutputBuffer.java:688) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:388) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:366) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.4
4]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.write(UTF8XmlOutput.java:381) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.Encoded.write(Encoded.java:137) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.output.UTF8XmlOutput.attribute(UTF8XmlOutput.java:224) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.attribute(XMLSerializer.java:416) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.AttributeProperty.serializeAttributes(AttributeProperty.java:73) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.
3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeAttributes(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:352) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:
2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:659) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:39) ~[jaxb-runt
ime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:142) ~[jaxb-runtime
-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:129) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2
.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:329) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:666) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:128) ~[jaxb-r
untime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:329) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:666) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:128) ~[jaxb-r
untime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:329) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:666) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:39) ~[jaxb-runt
ime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:142) ~[jaxb-runtime
-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:129) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2
.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:329) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:666) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.serializeItem(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:39) ~[jaxb-runt
ime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.serializeListBody(ArrayElementProperty.java:142) ~[jaxb-runtime
-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayERProperty.serializeBody(ArrayERProperty.java:129) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2
.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:329) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsXsiType(XMLSerializer.java:666) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.serializeBody(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:128) ~[jaxb-r
untime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeBody(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:329) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsSoleContent(XMLSerializer.java:563) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:310) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:464) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:298) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.marshal(MarshallerImpl.java:226) ~[jaxb-runtime-2.3.3.jar!/:2.3.3]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter.writeToResult(Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConv
erter.java:183) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.xml.AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(AbstractXmlHttpMessageConverter.java
:85) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:227) ~[spring-web
-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(
AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:293) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestRespons
eBodyMethodProcessor.java:181) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValu
eHandlerComposite.java:78) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandl
erMethod.java:124) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHand
lerAdapter.java:894) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAd
apter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[sp
ring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3
.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5
]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar!/:5
.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0
.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!
/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0
.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!
/:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.ja
r!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.
5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0
.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!
/:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3
.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.
5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0
.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!
/:9.0.44]
    at datadog.trace.instrumentation.springweb.HandlerMappingResourceNameFilter.doFilterInternal(HandlerMappingResourceNameFilte
r.java:49) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.
5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0
.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!
/:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:93) ~[
spring-boot-actuator-2.4.4.jar!/:2.4.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.
5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0
.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!
/:9.0.44]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.
3.5.jar!/:5.3.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.3.5.jar!/:5.3.
5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0
.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!
/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.
44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.4
4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9
.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:
9.0.44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.
44]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.44]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.44.jar!/:9.0.4
4]
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue

Comment: Still not yet. If you found anything let me know also.

Comment: Our latest theory (although we haven't confirmed it yet) is that kubernetes is throttling the CPU on the service when it tries to do a big GC spike, which causes the network thread that should respond to the metrics endpoint to take ages, and the Broken Pipe is actually just the metrics endpoint that we poll returning more slowly than Prometheus waits for it - resulting in this Broken Pipe exception (you can see in the stacktrace that it is involving "WebMvcMetricsFilter"). This is just an unconfirmed theory at the moment though, but these exceptions do seem to roughly coincide with GC spikes

Comment: I was not able to fix this issue. But when I add response as a gzip in spring boot this error throwing count got less. Also performance test breaking point also got increased with this gzip change. Still not able to identify the issue in here.

Answer (score 0):

I receive same exception in my rest controller. This exception occurs if client close tcp connection but server-side try to send data to client.

You can do two things:

- Increase client's timeout
- Decrease server's processing time for the specific api

PS: I did write the answer for who will find the question in feature. I'm almost 3 years late for "Dui Samarasinghe".

Edit: In my situation i solve the problem to adding index to my db. I decrease server's processing time with that.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).